# How to get SQL Server Management Studio tab messages in PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

With Powershell, I execute a SQL script which returns a generated script in the tab "Messages" of SQL Server Management Studio. But I can't get it in PowerShell.

When I do this :

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
[ref]$e = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException
$ps.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn( "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100", $e ) | Out-Null
$ps.AddCommand( "Invoke-Sqlcmd" ).AddParameter( "ServerInstance", "localhost").AddParameter( "Database", "MyDatabase").AddParameter("InputFile", "D:\MyScript.sql").AddParameter("Verbose")
$ps.Invoke()
$ps.Streams
$ps.Streams.Verbose | % { $_.Message | Out-File -Append D:\SqlLog.txt }
```

I get this error :

```
PS D:\NEMO\Scripts\Database> $ps.Invoke()
Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:1 char:11
+ $ps.Invoke <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So make Powershell to output messages is not that simple and it works only in command-line i think.  Try this

```
write-host $line
    Start-Transcript $outputfilepath
    $ScriptParams = "DatabaseName=$line" "
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Username $SQLAdminUser -Password $SQLAdminPwd -InputFile "D:\File.sql" -verbose -Variable $ScriptParams 
    Stop-Transcript
```